# SQL query cannot create user's table

Tags: mysql, create-table

I don't understand why this query wouldn't work. This query was working until I wanted to add the last column "groups".

```
CREATE TABLE users(
 id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 username CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(100),
 password VARCHAR(30),
 email VARCHAR(100),
 groups VARCHAR(100),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Won't work isn't a problem description. Is there an error? What is its expected behavior compared to the actual behavior?

Comment: Worked fine on SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/729454 Are you sure you didn't made a typo and use `group` instead of `groups`? That would trigger syntax error since `group` is a reserved word

Comment: Could you please show the error that you get and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“groups” is a reserved name in MySQL, if you really want to use It then you can avoid it by using backticks like:

```
`groups`
```

Comment: It is in [MySQL-8.0 (and probably onwards)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07facd4148c3754f3f93bfa696010546), [reference of reserved keywords in MySQL-8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @danblack 8.0.2!!

Comment: My sincere and unreserved apologizes to all 8.0.1 and 8.0.0 users who I've placed in operational chaos with such reckless indifference due to the precision nature of versioning and its profound impact on the reserved keyword `groups` and its behavior in said versions, its to you I say sorry⸮

Answer (score 1):

**GROUPS** is a new reserved keyword added in Mysql v8.0

> Either you can use a different name in place of groups like bunch or cluster

OR

> Use backticks for `groups`, but make sure you use backticks everywhere you use `groups`

You can check the list of [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G) in Mysql v8.0